# LinkageError with Spring 5 during upgrade

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, linkageerror

We're upgrading to Spring 5 and Hibernate 5 and Java 1.8.  But as we do so we're getting LinkageError.

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when overriding method "org/springframework/cache/annotation/AnnotationCacheOperationSource$CacheOperationProvider.getCacheOperations(Lorg/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheAnnotationParser;)Ljava/util/Collection;" during creation of class "org/springframework/cache/annotation/AnnotationCacheOperationSource$$Lambda$210/000000001AD36180": loader "java/lang/InternalAnonymousClassLoader@1337bd9b" of class "org/springframework/cache/annotation/AnnotationCacheOperationSource$$Lambda$210/000000001AD36180" and loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@d5b1949f" of class "org/springframework/cache/annotation/AnnotationCacheOperationSource$CacheOperationProvider" have different types for the method signature
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.spinInnerClass(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:339)
    at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.buildCallSite(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:206)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:315)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.resolveInvokeDynamic(MethodHandle.java:841)
    ... 107 more
Related cause:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceTarge' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/app-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'txManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/app-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'enoteSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/app-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when overriding method "org/hibernate/tool/schema/spi/DelayedDropRegistry.registerOnCloseAction(Lorg/hibernate/tool/schema/spi/DelayedDropAction;)V" during creation of class "org/hibernate/internal/SessionFactoryImpl$$Lambda$207/000000001B931600": loader "java/lang/InternalAnonymousClassLoader@1337bd9b" of class "org/hibernate/internal/SessionFactoryImpl$$Lambda$207/000000001B931600" and loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@d5b1949f" of class "org/hibernate/tool/schema/spi/DelayedDropRegistry" have different types for the method signature
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
```

And then a little lower:

```
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when overriding method "org/hibernate/tool/schema/spi/DelayedDropRegistry.registerOnCloseAction(Lorg/hibernate/tool/schema/spi/DelayedDropAction;)V" during creation of class "org/hibernate/internal/SessionFactoryImpl$$Lambda$207/000000001B931600": loader "java/lang/InternalAnonymousClassLoader@1337bd9b" of class "org/hibernate/internal/SessionFactoryImpl$$Lambda$207/000000001B931600" and loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@d5b1949f" of class "org/hibernate/tool/schema/spi/DelayedDropRegistry" have different types for the method signature
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:535)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1761)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1698)
    ... 156 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when overriding method "org/hibernate/tool/schema/spi/DelayedDropRegistry.registerOnCloseAction(Lorg/hibernate/tool/schema/spi/DelayedDropAction;)V" during creation of class "org/hibernate/internal/SessionFactoryImpl$$Lambda$207/000000001B931600": loader "java/lang/InternalAnonymousClassLoader@1337bd9b" of class "org/hibernate/internal/SessionFactoryImpl$$Lambda$207/000000001B931600" and loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@d5b1949f" of class "org/hibernate/tool/schema/spi/DelayedDropRegistry" have different types for the method signature
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.spinInnerClass(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:339)
    at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.buildCallSite(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:206)
```

I think one is a cascade off the other.  Anyone know what might be causing this?  Seems like mismatching versions of jars, but I can't figure out which.

Comment: Your dependencies are having a fit with each other, from what I can tell. Might be a pom issue.

Comment: We're not on Maven unfortunately.   We figure that it's either some clashing dependencies OR that maybe multiple classloaders are trying to load the same thing.  We were leaning towards the latter, but the class loader viewer doesn't show that.